# Cann't I set title and Image to the right bar item on navigation bar at the same time in storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I want to set the right button item to be this:

[image]

It has the title and the down image.

But in storyboard, I can not do that:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I only can set one of the title and image, if I set image, I can not set the title, if I set the title, I can not set the image.

I have tried use the UIButton and the Button Bar Item to do it, get the same result.

Some friend know how to do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add drag UIButton to rightBarItem in storyBoard . and customise that button as per your needs ..

Check View hierarchy after adding UIButton .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this add the custom view to your bar button item

```
var RightView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44))
// you can add in RightView, your title in uilable and your image in imageview  
var RightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: RightView)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = RightBarButton
```